# Creating the Base Entity class in relational entity classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

The json below is what was sent to me, when I findByPinCode. I have created relations between them in the following accordance with the json answer. Here are the relationships.

```
{
  "RequestIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "Status": {
    "Name": "string",
    "Code": 0,
    "Message": "string"
  },
  "Response": {
    "Person": {
      "Pin": "string",
      "LastName": "string",
      "FirstName": "string",
      "FatherName": "string",
      "BirthDate": "string"
    },
    "Company": {
      "Voen": "string",
      "Name": "string",
      "PersonType": "string",
      "Persons": [
        {
          "Pin": "string",
          "LastName": "string",
          "FirstName": "string",
          "FatherName": "string",
          "BirthDate": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Farms": [
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "string",
        "Fields": [
          {
            "VillageName": "string",
            "DocType": "string",
            "FieldAmount": 0,
            "Unit": "string",
            "Plants": [
              {
                "Name": "string",
                "FieldAmount": 0,
                "Unit": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Animals": [
          {
            "Sort": "string",
            "Count": 0
          }
        ],
        "Bees": [
          {
            "Sort": "string",
            "Count": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(One)Company To (Many)Persons

(One)FarmInfo To (Many)FarmFields

(One)FarmFields To (Many)Plants

(One)FarmInfo To (Many)Animals

(One)FarmInfo To (Many)Bees

and thus converting them to my dto class first. Then I want to convert them to my entity classes and persist them completely to the database.

This is my DTO class.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FarmInfoMainResult {

    @JsonProperty(value = "RequestIdentifier")
    private String requestIdentifier;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Status")
    private ResponseStatus status;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Response")
    private FarmInfoData response;
}
```

and this is my business logic layer of method, which I want to that in here convertint the dto class to the BaseEntity class and at the end of I want to persist BaseEntity class to the database.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<FarmInfoMainResult> findFarmInfoByPin(String pin, String username, String branchCode) {
    String requestIdentifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ResponseEntity<FarmInfoMainResult> farmInfoPinServiceResponse = clientUtility.getForObject(farmInfoForPinUrl + pin, requestIdentifier, FarmInfoMainResult.class);
    System.out.println("farmInfoPinServiceResponse " + farmInfoPinServiceResponse.getBody());
    /*
    Here are I want to convert farmInfoPinServiceResponse variable to the my Base Entity class and so persist it to the database, so that 
    thus, values will be automatically added to them as they are related to each other in other relational databases.
     */
    return farmInfoPinServiceResponse;
}



@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String requestIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Status status;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Response response;

}
```

But I am getting the following error in my Response class. `basic' attribute type should not be a container`

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private PersonFarmInfo personFarmInfo;

    private CompanyFarmInfo companyFarmInfo;

    private FarmInfo farmInfo;

    private FarmFieldInfo farmFieldInfo;

    private FarmPlantInfo farmPlantInfo;

    private FarmAnimalInfo farmAnimalInfo;

    private FarmBeeInfo farmBeeInfo;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "response")
    private BaseEntity baseEntity;
}
```

If I don't create main entity class, there will be a situation like this. I will add the properties of each class that is in the dto to the properties of each of my entity class and print them to the database. But by insert to a single entity class I want others to be affected as well. I wanted to solve the issue by creating a main entity class like this, but I'm getting the following error.

As I said at the beginning, the codes below do this by separating them into parts. These codes my old version codes.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<FarmInfoMainResult> findFarmInfoByPin(String pin, String username, String branchCode) {
    String requestIdentifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ResponseEntity<FarmInfoMainResult> farmInfoPinServiceResponse = clientUtility.getForObject(farmInfoForPinUrl + pin, requestIdentifier, FarmInfoMainResult.class);
    System.out.println("farmInfoPinServiceResponse " + farmInfoPinServiceResponse.getBody());
    saveFarmInfoPin(farmInfoPinServiceResponse.getBody(), username, branchCode, pin);
    return farmInfoPinServiceResponse;
}
```

Here I am sending the object stored in dto to my saveFarmInfoPin method.Then this method works. Here, my method saves all my object values stored in dto separately.

```
private void saveFarmInfoPin(FarmInfoMainResult farmInfoMainResult, String username, String branchcode, String pin) {
        // try {
        if (farmInfoMainResult.getResponse() != null) {
            saveFarmInfoPersonPin(farmInfoMainResult.getResponse().getPerson(), farmInfoMainResult.getRequestIdentifier(), username, branchcode, pin);
            saveFarmInfoCompanyPin(farmInfoMainResult.getResponse().getCompany(), farmInfoMainResult.getRequestIdentifier(), username, branchcode);
            saveFarminfo(farmInfoMainResult.getResponse().getFarms());
      /*  } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */

        }
    }
```

Finally, my following methods divide each of my dto objects into parts, first converting them to my entity class, and then adding them to the database via repository.

```
private void saveFarmInfoPersonPin(FarmInfoPerson farmInfoPersonDto, String requestIdentifier, String username, String branchCode, String pin) {
    if (farmInfoPersonDto != null) {
        FarmPersonInfo newFarmInfoPerson = new FarmPersonInfo();
        newFarmInfoPerson.setRequestIdentifier(requestIdentifier);

        newFarmInfoPerson.setBranchCode(branchCode);
        newFarmInfoPerson.setUsername(username);
        newFarmInfoPerson.setPin(pin);

        newFarmInfoPerson.setPin(farmInfoPersonDto.getPin());
        newFarmInfoPerson.setFatherName(farmInfoPersonDto.getFatherName());
        newFarmInfoPerson.setFirstName(farmInfoPersonDto.getFirstName());
        newFarmInfoPerson.setBirthDate(farmInfoPersonDto.getBirthDate());
        personFarmInfoRepository.save(newFarmInfoPerson);
    }
}


private void saveFarmInfoCompanyPin(FarmInfoCompany farmInfoCompany, String requestIdentifier, String username, String branchCode) {

    List<FarmPersonInfo> newFarmInfoPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (farmInfoCompany != null) {

        FarmCompanyInfo newCompanyFarmInfo = new FarmCompanyInfo();
        newCompanyFarmInfo.setName(farmInfoCompany.getName());

        newCompanyFarmInfo.setRequestIdentifier(requestIdentifier);
        newCompanyFarmInfo.setUsername(username);
        newCompanyFarmInfo.setBranchCode(branchCode);

        newCompanyFarmInfo.setPersonType(farmInfoCompany.getPersonType());
        newCompanyFarmInfo.setVoen(farmInfoCompany.getVoen());
        // CompanyFarmInfo companyFarmInfo = companyFarmInfoRepository.save(newCompanyFarmInfo);


        for (FarmInfoPerson farmInfoPerson : farmInfoCompany.getPersons()) {
            FarmPersonInfo personInfo = new FarmPersonInfo();
            personInfo.setPin(farmInfoPerson.getPin());
            personInfo.setFatherName(farmInfoPerson.getFatherName());
            personInfo.setFirstName(farmInfoPerson.getFirstName());
            personInfo.setBirthDate(farmInfoPerson.getBirthDate());

            personInfo.setFarmCompanyInfo(newCompanyFarmInfo); 

            newFarmInfoPersonList.add(personInfo);
        }
        personFarmInfoRepository.saveAll(newFarmInfoPersonList);
    }
}


private void saveFarminfo(List<FarmInfoFarm> farmInfoFarms) {

    List<FarmFieldInfo> newFarmFieldInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FarmAnimalInfo> newFarmAnimalInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FarmBeeInfo> newFarmBeeInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FarmPlantInfo> newFarmPlantInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (FarmInfoFarm farmInfoFarm : farmInfoFarms) {
        FarmInfo newFarmInfo = new FarmInfo();
        newFarmInfo.setName(farmInfoFarm.getName());
        newFarmInfo.setFarmInfoId(farmInfoFarm.getId());
        FarmInfo farmInfo = farmInfoRepository.save(newFarmInfo); 
        
        for (FarmInfoField farmInfoField : farmInfoFarm.getFields()) {
            FarmFieldInfo newFarmFieldInfo = new FarmFieldInfo();

            newFarmFieldInfo.setVillageName(farmInfoField.getVillageName());
            newFarmFieldInfo.setDocType(farmInfoField.getDocType());
            newFarmFieldInfo.setFieldAmount(farmInfoField.getFieldAmount());
            newFarmFieldInfo.setUnit(farmInfoField.getUnit());

            newFarmFieldInfo.setFarmInfo(farmInfo); 

            newFarmFieldInfoList.add(newFarmFieldInfo);

            for (FarmInfoPlant farmInfoPlant : farmInfoField.getPlants()) {
                FarmPlantInfo newfarmPlantInfo = new FarmPlantInfo();
                newfarmPlantInfo.setName(farmInfoPlant.getName());
                newfarmPlantInfo.setFieldAmount(farmInfoPlant.getFieldAmount());
                newfarmPlantInfo.setUnit(farmInfoPlant.getUnit());

                newfarmPlantInfo.setFarmFieldInfo(newFarmFieldInfo);

                newFarmPlantInfoList.add(newfarmPlantInfo);

            }
            farmPlantInfoRepository.saveAll(newFarmPlantInfoList);
        }
        farmFieldInfoRepository.saveAll(newFarmFieldInfoList);

        for (FarmInfoAnimal farmInfoAnimal : farmInfoFarm.getAnimals()) {
            FarmAnimalInfo newFarmAnimalInfo = new FarmAnimalInfo();
            newFarmAnimalInfo.setCount(farmInfoAnimal.getCount());
            newFarmAnimalInfo.setSort(farmInfoAnimal.getSort());
            newFarmAnimalInfo.setFarmInfo(farmInfo);
            newFarmAnimalInfoList.add(newFarmAnimalInfo);
        }
        farmAnimalInfoRepository.saveAll(newFarmAnimalInfoList);

        for (FarmInfoBee farmInfoBee : farmInfoFarm.getBees()) {
            FarmBeeInfo newfarmBeeInfo = new FarmBeeInfo();
            newfarmBeeInfo.setCount(farmInfoBee.getCount());
            newfarmBeeInfo.setSort(farmInfoBee.getSort());
            newfarmBeeInfo.setFarmInfo(farmInfo);
            newFarmBeeInfoList.add(newfarmBeeInfo);
        }
        farmBeeInfoRepository.saveAll(newFarmBeeInfoList);
    }


}
```

But as I said, instead of separating them all into separate-parts, can I add all of these objects to my main entity class and bring all these particles together through just one method?

I'm thinking of something like this, now I will use jackson to convert all the values in the json value I have received to the classes it belongs to, then I will add them to my main class and finally add my main class to my database. Since the main class will already have all the relations in itself, I think that all of them will be affected by doing this operation once.

Comment: Can you please add your stack trace? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get error to show what you said in my project.

Comment: So you don't get an error like `basic' attribute type should not be a container`? Does it have more detailed information?

Comment: It's not a compilation error, it just gives a warning message on it.

Comment: "But I am getting the following error in my Response class. ". This is what you wrote. Is it an error or is it a warning? What is not working then?

Comment: I've solved it now, thanks for everything.

Comment: Then either delete the question or add the solution as an answer. Thanks!